# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(String)" because "a1.JsonConfig.configProperties" is null

Tags: java

I am writing the below code for a login page by using JSON for the data-driven but it showing "Cannot invoke "org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(String)" because "a1.JsonConfig.configProperties" is null"

```
package a1;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonConfig {

    static JSONObject configProperties;

    public static void loadConfig() {
        try {
            configProperties = new JSONObject(
                    new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src\\main\\java\\Config.json"))));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("unable to load the json file path");

        }

    }

    public static String getUserName(String userName) {

        return configProperties.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject(userName).getString("username");
    }

    public static String getPassword(String userName) {

        return configProperties.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject(userName).getString("password");
    }

}
```